# Attaching youtube video player into textview

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit

I've been struggling to find a library in which it support my need, and that is to embed a yt video player into a text view. So, what I'm basically trying to do is to create something similar to Reddit in which it have a yt vide inside the thread details.

Currently, i am using NSAttributedString to store the yt thumbnail image and add it into the textView, and in order to play the video, it'll navigate to another view that loads the yt video. It's an okay solution but not the solution that I want

Therefore, are there any solution on how to overcome this problem? Thank you

What i want. :
[image: The result that I want]

ps:  the image is currently using image attachment aka NSAttributedString, not an UIview with youtube player

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextattachmentviewprovider

Comment: i'm sorry, the app support minimum of ios 11